# Unable to access the ec2 Geronimo port from outside

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2

I setup geronimo on ec2 cent os environment.It started successfully.It is running on port 8080.I am able to telnet on the server.But when i telnet outside the server, unable to connect to the server.Do i need to change any configuration ?

when i ran netstat -an.I can see the following line.

```
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to telnet to this server from the outside server (port=8080)? If that is the case, you will have to ease up your security profile and allow TCP port 8080 from anyIp (or specific IPs that you want to).

Comment: 8080 is open in the security profile.still it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is block by iptables.due to this i am unable to telnet from outside the machine. This is happening only on ec2 centos machine.I checked on ubuntu and connections are not blocked.Once solution is to stop the iptables service.

```
service iptables stop
```

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This application seems to be listening on the IPv6 address. First check whether the machine is reachable over ipv6 from the outside machine before making the telnet connection. Use global ipv6 address if your trying to access the machine outside the LAN network.